# select value from website dropdown by vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, browser-automation

i am trying to select value in website drop and i try so many way but nothing works
I am stuck at one point where I need to select value from the drop-down box
I have four drop down and i want to select option drop down then goto next drop down and ima stuck at first drop down

```
Sub Select_dropdown_item()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim drp As Variant
dname = Range("A1").Value
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://anyror.gujarat.gov.in/"
    While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    IE.document.getElementById("Button1").Click

If IE.LocationURL = "https://anyror.gujarat.gov.in/CustomError.htm" Then
IE.Quit
MsgBox ("website can not comunicate with server")
Else
    ''if the script fails, activate the delay
'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

End If
Set drp = IE.document.getElementById("ddlDistrict")
For x = 0 To drp.Options.Length - 1
If drp.Options(x).Value = dname Then
drp.selectedIndex = x
Exit For
End If
Next
End Sub
```

it show error 13 type mismatch
on line

```
Set drp = IE.document.getElementById("ddlDistrict")
```

so plz help
this is my html code for first drop down

```
    <option selected="selected" value="0">પસંદ કરો</option>
    <option value="01">કચ્છ</option>
    <option value="02">બનાસકાંઠા</option>
    <option value="03">પાટણ</option>
    <option value="04">મહેસાણા</option>
    <option value="05">સાબરકાંઠા</option>
    <option value="06">ગાંધીનગર</option>
    <option value="07">અમદાવાદ</option>
    <option value="08">સુરેન્દ્રનગર</option>
    <option value="09">રાજકોટ</option>
    <option value="10">જામનગર</option>
    <option value="11">પોરબંદર</option>
    <option value="12">જુનાગઢ</option>
    <option value="13">અમરેલી</option>
    <option value="14">ભાવનગર</option>
    <option value="15">આણંદ</option>
    <option value="16">ખેડા</option>
    <option value="17">પંચમહાલ</option>
    <option value="18">દાહોદ</option>
    <option value="19">વડોદરા</option>
    <option value="20">નર્મદા</option>
    <option value="21">ભરુચ</option>
    <option value="22">સુરત</option>
    <option value="23">ડાંગ</option>
    <option value="24">નવસારી</option>
    <option value="25">વલસાડ</option>
    <option value="26">તાપી</option>
    <option value="27">દેવભુમિ દ્વારકા</option>
    <option value="28">મોરબી</option>
    <option value="29">ગીર સોમનાથ</option>
    <option value="30">બોટાદ</option>
    <option value="31">અરવલ્લી</option>
    <option value="32">મહિસાગર</option>
    <option value="33">છોટાઉદેપુર</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have executed the code on my machine and it is working fine in debug mode.
I'd suggest to add a wait of 5-10 seconds before the line in which you are getting the drop down object.

```
**Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")**
Set drp = IE.document.getElementById("ddlDistrict")
For x = 0 To drp.Options.Length - 1
If drp.Options(x).Value = dname Then
```

It should work fine but will depend on the server lag and your internet speed as well.

Comment: i use advise now it show object required error on line  `For x = 0 To drp.Options.Length - 1` so what do i do plz help

Answer (score 1):

Use a css attribute=value selector and concatenate in the variable

```
ie.document.querySelector("[value='" + dname + "']").Selected = True
```

If more than one dropdown has this value, and provided your given id is correct and for the appropriate dropdown, you may wish to add the parent id to isolate the appropriate dropdown

```
ie.document.querySelector("#ddlDistrict [value='" + dname + "']").Selected = True
```

Comment: now it show object required error on line `ie.document.querySelector("#ddlDistrict [value='" + dname + "']").Selected = True` plz help

Comment: do you have a proper page load wait before? Does the error go away if you step slowly through code pressing F8?

Comment: Did you step through with F8?